# java mail polling read inline or embedded images (smileys) from the mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am new in java mail polling and i have create one type of conversation application in this if user send mail to each other then i read that from them mail and post as new message in conversation.

now issue is that, what to do if there is smileys, inline or embedded images. for example in gmail mail we can send smileys also now how read that smile and post on to the over page. please give me some proper solution for this.

[image: This type of the smileys.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to download the inline images + icons from the mail.

```
  private String getAttachments(Message message, HttpServletRequest request) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    String contentType = message.getContentType();
    String attachFiles="";
    if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
        // content may contain attachments
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
        for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
            String disposition =part.getDisposition();
            String file=part.getFileName();
            //External attachments
            if (disposition != null && Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                // this part is attachment
                String fileName = new Date().getTime()+ "_"+ part.getFileName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+", "_"); //To make attachment name uniq we are adding current datatime before name.
                attachFiles += fileName + ","; //concrete all attachment's name with comma separated.                  
                part.saveFile(new File(request
                        .getSession()
                        .getServletContext()
                        .getRealPath(
                                "/WEB-INF/attechments/"
                                        + fileName)));   //To save the attachment file at specific location.
      //                    LOG.info("\n\t Path :- " +request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/attechments/" + fileName));
            }
            //Inline Attachments
            else if (disposition != null && Part.INLINE.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                // this part is attachment
                String fileName = new Date().getTime()+ "_"+ part.getFileName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+", "_"); //To make attachment name uniq we are adding current datatime before name.
              //  attachFiles += fileName + ","; //concrete all attachment's name with comma separated.                  
                part.saveFile(new File(request
                        .getSession()
                        .getServletContext()
                        .getRealPath(
                                "/WEB-INF/attechments/"
                                        + fileName)));   //To save the attachment file at specific location.
 //                    LOG.info("\n\t Path :- " +request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/attechments/" + fileName));
            }
            //Inline icons and smileys
            else if(file != null && disposition==null)
            {
                String fileName = new Date().getTime()+ "_"+ part.getFileName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+", "_");
            //  attachFiles += fileName + ","; //concrete all attachment's name with comma separated.
                 part.saveFile(new File(request
                        .getSession()
                        .getServletContext()
                        .getRealPath(
                                "/WEB-INF/attechments/"
                                        + fileName))); 

            }
        }
    }
     if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
         attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 1);
     }
    return attachFiles;
}
```

Comment: I have now only one issue how to change <img src="cid:XXX"> with my original path

Comment: Uday A. Navapara thanx, had simillar issue and found my own mistake thanks to your code. However did You manage to think of some method how to replace the img with cid with Your image?